# Will using cryptography in my app restrict its availability?

Tags: cryptography, windows-store-apps

I see that the [Windows Store submission process](http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2012/09/08/The-Windows-Store-Submission-Process.aspx) asks about whether your app uses encryption. I am planning on doing so. Why do they ask this? Will encyption restrict countries in which the app will be made available?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking a specific vendor, not the many public communities.

Comment: Asking a specific vendor? What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that we can not speak for the vendor (Microsoft) about what Microsoft asks about when it asks for Yes/No on "your app uses encryption". That is a more broad close-description for the same reasons that why questions are closed when asking for a link or off-site resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has information about the issue [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694069.aspx). The upshot seems to be that you can put it in the store, but you need to give them information about the crypto that it uses via an [ECCN](http://www.bis.doc.gov/licensing/do_i_needaneccn.html) (Export Commodity Classification Number). Then they handle automatically these issues (i.e., they won't sell it illegally). You should be fine (the ban on crypto export has been lifted or a long time).

Answer (score 1):

Cryptography has issues on importing. For lot of countries the [Wassenaar Arrangement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wassenaar_Arrangement) applies, which restrict importing cryptography for protecting communication

Category 5 - Part 2
http://www.wassenaar.org/controllists/index.html

And this article: [Restrictions on the import of cryptography - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrictions_on_the_import_of_cryptography)